# Blocked from asking questions for absolutely no reason

Tags: support, post-ban

I am suddenly unable to post any questions and am presented with the option to edit my existing questions to make them better instead. My questions (aside from 1 which I deleted) are mostly very old, what would I gain from editing them? I don't even work with some of the stuff I asked questions on.

What am I supposed to do exactly in this case?

Also, I deleted one question because I suspected it to be the cause for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78103697/how-to-close-discord-js-modal-on-awaitmodalsubmit-error, even though it does not strike me as a poorly written question.

Comment: Note that deleting questions does not remove them from consideration by this algorithm

Comment: *what would I gain from editing them*: You would gain the ability to ask questions again. And you would do the community a service by providing high quality questions.

Comment: Are you sure that this is your only deleted question (note, that questions are also automatically deleted by the system after some time). In your visible questions, there is only a single one that has a negative score, that should not be enough to get you question banned.

Comment: It's not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78104086/can-we-close-discord-modals and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73846774/printing-values-of-type-hwnd are both relatively recent and negatively scored

Comment: "I am suddenly unable to post any questions..." <-- that does not appear to be accurate. It wasn't sudden. The system recorded that you were warned about quality issues with your prior questions and a possible question ban on 1) 2024-02-24 at 21:24:45Z prior to posting [this question](//stackoverflow.com/q/78054048); 2) 2024-03-04 at 19:42:15Z prior to posting [this question](//stackoverflow.com/q/78103697); and 3) 2024-03-04 at 21:10:55Z prior to posting [this question](//stackoverflow.com/q/78104086). On all three occasions, you chose to go ahead with posting your question.

Comment: What does editing it do exactly? I don't know how to edit them anymore I'd rather get rid of them

Comment: and start over. Plus, wouldn't it take ages for the system to check whether my questions are higher quality after editing?

Comment: "What does editing it do exactly?" - The question ban is mostly about **non-positive score** of some of your questions. Would any of of those question change their score to positive value, the ban probably has been removed (probably - because no one knows the exact algorithm of the ban). Your edits could help a question to attract an upvote. The duplicate question contains more details.

Comment: You have 8 questions that haven’t been deleted and none of them are well received. I suspect you have several deleted questions which you erroneously deleted. Those questions likely were downvoted. You also were warned that your questions were not well received. Question bans are a result of a continued pattern of asking questions that are not well received. “I'd rather get rid of them” - It’s too late for that. You asked the question so now you’re responsible for the quality of the question. Improvement of the quality of ALL your questions is the only way out of a question ban.

Comment: "what would I gain from editing them?" - if you are starting from this position, then you have fundamentally misunderstood the site. This is **not** a place where you come to ask a question about a problem that you, personally, are experiencing, because you, personally, need or want an answer so that you, personally, can continue doing your work. It is a place where you ask a question to **help build a reference library** - the same one where you, personally, can get that help by *finding an existing question*, which exists *because someone else was not selfish*.

Comment: Additional recommended reading (I wrote this, on meta.stackexchange): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391761

Comment: thank you. all those bad qs are very niche tho so editing will be futile and since they are old they wont attract any attention. anyways

Comment: You are responding to comments here, and that is good. One key for the future, when you can re-ask a question in 6 months, is to be sure to follow the question closely for at least 1 to 2 hours after asking, and to promptly respond positively to any comments, especially if made in suggestion on how to improve the question.

Comment: If you want sympathy, in my opinion the bans are too long and too harsh. But your comments, which are *not* evil at all but rather straightforward and matter-of-fact, nevertheless suggest that you ignored all the warnings and only starting paying attention when the ban anvil fell on you. So that reinforces that some kind of ban is necessary. Lots of users do this, we all tend to click through warnings to get to the heart of the matter and get our work done, but that's not a good practice on these sites.

Comment: very good, i understand